# failed to create jvm error code 4 android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm, ide

I was just updated my last Android Studio and got this error:

> failed to create jvm error code -4
>   JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
>   If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in
>   Which is not solved.

Comment: I told my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616303/failed-to-create-jvmerror-code-6-android-studio/41678833#41678833) not sure what was the error about

Comment: I have also [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 55):

Go to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions`

Open it with notepad. some times it will not be editable so give administrative permission and change the following attributes:

`-Xmx512m` to `-Xmx256m`

`-XX:MaxPermSize=250m` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

Or change:

`-Xmx750m` to `-Xmx512m`

`-XX:MaxPermSize=350m` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=250m`

Comment: Thanks, second solution works for me also. Thanks :)

Comment: hmm it works but I just curious what is the actual problem behind it?

Comment: @LongDao You got any article why this problem accord.. Even m also searching but not getting any proper article or reason behind that..

Comment: Check this file as well C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions

Answer (score 23):

I have rechecked the java path but its not working in my case. So I deleted the Android Studio settings folder in my user folder.

```
C:\Users\my_username.AndroidStudio
```

Then re-open Android Studio then everything work fine for me.

In some case is in `C:/Users/my_username/.AndroidStudio3.0/studio64.vmoptions.`

Comment: Changing the vmoptions due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350847/android-studio-using-100-cpu-on-an-i7-processor-for-project-rebuild because that hopefully fix the sluggishness of Android build, will cause this error? Unbelievable. Never thought of it.

Comment: In my case it was C:/Users/myuser/.AndroidStudio3.0/studio64.vmoptions. It worked

Comment: I didn't have to delete the whole folder, only the studdio64.vmoptions file.

Comment: Deleting VMOPTIONS File and restarting Android Studio again worked but the file was in config directory so better search it inside `.AndroidStudio3.5/` folder because they're moving it around.

Comment: Works great with 3.5 version
in my case "failed to create jvm" err started because trying to speed up AStudio went to 
Help - Edit Custom VM options ... then A.S. created a file called studio64.vmoptions

 C:/Users/my_username/.AndroidStudio3.5/config/studio64.vmoptions.

Answer (score 10):

For Android Studio 4+ You need to remove «\studio.exe.vmoptions» or «studio64.exe.vmoptions»
Here is the path

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\{studio version}
```

Comment: yessss, finally write answer

Answer (score 8):

finally I got answer here.
You need to change vmoptions file from android studio.

> Go to Program files > Android > Android Studio > Bin > android studio.exe
>   vmoptions file.

Open it with notepad and change the following attributes :

Change `-Xmx512m to -Xmx256m` and `-XX:MaxPermSize=250m` to -`XX:MaxPermSize=128m`
or

Change `-Xmx750m to -Xmx512m` and `-XX:MaxPermSize=350m` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=250m`

Comment: but now daemon process doesn't start

Answer (score 7):

If you have recently modified *Custom VM Options* using Help menu, then you should undo your changes or if you have created a new VM options file, remove it.
 The file can be found on this path:

> C:\Users\.AndroidStudio2.1

Answer (score 2):

just updating my JDK worked for me! :D
If it still doesn't work, try updating Android Studio.

Comment: How can I update Android Studio if Android Studio didn't open because of this error? Error 4 and 6 doesn't open up the Android Studio for me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was run android studio as an administrator.  Just right click on the icon on your desktop (do not try to do it with a shortcut pinned to your taskbar) and click run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions

Delete studio64.exe.vmoptions file

That's what worked for me