# Error after upgrading android studio 1 to 2 , won't launch 

Tags: android, android-studio, java-6, android-studio-2.0

## when i try to lunch android studio after upgrade i get

[image]

## Android studio Ver. info

[image]

## Java_Home environment variables

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions`

Open it with notepad. some times it will not be editable so give administrative permission and change the following attributes:

`-Xmx512m` to `-Xmx256m`

`-XX:MaxPermSize=250m` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

Or change:

`-Xmx750m` to `-Xmx512m`

`-XX:MaxPermSize=350m` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=250m`

for more detail visit this [failed to create jvm error code 4 android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094132/failed-to-create-jvm-error-code-4-android-studio)