# Error launching Android Studio failed to create Jvm

Tags: android, android-studio

Error launching Android-Studio failed to create `jvm`..I have add environment variable also but still same error please help me...!! I am using windows 10 32 bit os.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to create jvm error code 4 android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094132/failed-to-create-jvm-error-code-4-android-studio)

Comment: can you restart your system,might help you. and clear temp or can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: Navigate to folder where android studio is installed.D:\android-studio\bin.There you will see two exe files "studio.exe" and "studio64.exe". Try opening studio with both of them because you might be using 32 bit version of java.

Comment: I have also [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\Users\yourname\.android\studio.exe.vmoptions----delete this file your problem solved