# Why is Android Studio v3.0.1 not running after installing successfully?

Tags: android, ide, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

I have installed Android Studio using the **/NCRC** tag by running the downloaded executable from the Command Prompt. The installation was successful.

However, when I run it for the first time, I get an error (**0xc0000020**)
[studio64.exe - Bad Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV61M.png)

When, I click **Ok** I get the following Dialog Box: [Error Launching Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NV8s.png)

Now, the following things I tried:

1. Initially I had JDK v9 installed, I uninstalled that and then installed JDK v8 and reset all the Environmental Variables.
2. I have set the **JAVA_HOME** , **JDK_HOME** Environment Variables. I have also included the path to the **jdk** , **jre** , **jdk/bin** , **jre/bin** folders.
3. I have downloaded Android Studio multiple times using **Firefox** , **Ninja Downloader** and also **Microsoft Edge** , yet the problem persists.
4. I have restarted multiple times.
5. Upon receiving the first error:

[studio64.exe - Bad Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV61M.png)

**I did the following things:**

- Copied **jvm.dll** from "...\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\server\" to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\server" Then, I
  re-ran Android Studio again. I got errors:

[Error-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxvpH.png) [Error-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5IeU.png)

- Similarly, I kept on adding the **dll** files from the **"...\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\"** folder into **"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\"** as per the errors that
  were shown.

[Error-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1lbl.png)

**Once all these steps were done, no further errors arose. However, Android Studio *does not* run anymore now.**

Is there any solution I can try to **install and run** Android Studio v3.0.1 ??

Comment: any reasons for /NCRC ? looks like files are corrupted

Comment: The Android Studio executable is not installing without setting the **NCRC** flag irrespective of the number of times I download, using any of the Download Mangers or Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is JAVA_HOME variable shall read JDK folder.
I'm meeting different problem; after Windows Update, Android Studio stopped to work giving error -6, failed to create JVM. I've installed the JDK and added all of the necessary Environment variables, but not able to solve it!

Comment: my problem was solved by this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155747/error-launching-android-studio-failed-to-create-jvm)

Comment: There is no such path available in my system. The path and files I have in my system is/are: **C:\Users\username\.android\studio\installer\firstrun** which is a data file.I deleted the file, but to no avail.

Comment: I found it in folder called ".AndroidStudio3.0". maybe it is because of version difference. So sorry for late response

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the temporary files, rebooted my PC, removed old downloads of Android Studio, re-downloaded using Edge and installed. This time it went off without a hitch. The same process did not work previously, yet, it worked now. Android Studio is successfully installed now and is running smoothly.

I have no clue as to what the exact problem was, but I think that the download was getting corrupted previously. Right now, the download wasn't getting corrupted and hence everything went smoothly. I did not need to set the **NCRC** flag to install either.