# Failed to create JVM Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my project I clicked `Invalidate and restart` then studio was closed and such error pop up appeared

[image]

I rebooted my computer. Then I updated my Java as well as updated the path to the Java dir

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

One more time rebooted my computer, but anyway the same error pop up

Also for me not clear why at last lines of error wrote that

> Failed to create JVM. JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Android\AndroidStudio3.3\jre\jre

Why does studio tries to get java by this path if in `system variables` path is - `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161`

**Also I have studio 3.2.1 and it is works, but studio 3.3.1 does not... So, as for me it is means that problem not in the java path**

What I am doing wrong?

*EDIT*

Just now I have reinstalled studio 3.3.1, but nothing changed... The same error

**EDIT**
Added this variable `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin` to PATH in System variables(image below), clicked `OK`, but it does not helped

[image]

**EDIT**
My variables

```
C:\Users\alexey.t>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\alexey.t\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=C035
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\alexey.t
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\alexey.t\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\PITON
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OneDrive=C:\Users\alexey.t\OneDrive
OS=Windows_NT
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common 
Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java
\javapath;C:\Users\alexey. t\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform- 
tools;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS
\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System3 2\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program 
Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client 
SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL 


Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161;C:\Users\alexey.t\AppData
\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS
\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modul es;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\alexey.t\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\alexey.t\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDNSDOMAIN=EWAVE.CO.IL
USERDOMAIN=EWAVE
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=EWAVE
USERNAME=Alexey.T
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\alexey.t
windir=C:\WINDOWS
```

**EDIT**

My vm options

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-da
```

**Feel free to ask, also let me know any of assumption**

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME is at JRE. You are not suppose to use JDK for JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @KunLun sorry for misunderstanding I have added incorrect image. Fixed. Actually it is jdk, take a loot now.

Comment: in CDM try this two commands 1) JAVA and 2) JAVAC . this both command run successfully?

Comment: @MayurDabhi java - is ok, but javac give me such output 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko did you have `JAVA_HOME\bin` into PATH variable?

Comment: @KunLun I have ONLY `JAVA_HOME` , not `JAVA_HOME\bin`

Comment: then problem in  your PATH veriable path fixed it

Comment: @shizhen I downloaded studio from https://developer.android.com/studio , it 64-bit

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: Hi @AlekseyTimoshchenko please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37813192/2298357

Comment: @KunLun edited my question, take a look please. Added that you asked, but it does not helped

Comment: @shizhen we are talking about PATH variable not about JAVA_HOME... yeah? because according to this guys @Mayur Dabhi and @KunLun I have to put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` , you don't think so?

Comment: Have you defined JAVA_HOME in user variables?

Comment: @shingo No, just in System variables

Comment: @shingo just now I added it at user variables, no it does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/949611/195957

Translate :

It is hard to say why this issue is came... For Android Studio don't need `JAVA_HOME` variable at all.

It mostly looks like that during the installation something goes wrong with AS settings.

Copying of dir `config` from previous working AS version `Users/username/.AndroidStudio3.2` in `.AndroidStudio3.3` can solve the problem.

Maybe problem exactly in `options/jdk.table.xml` file. Try to start with it firstly.

Answer (score 0):

1. In android studio, there is an embedded jre. By default android studio will be using this.  You have to change this settings some how. In ubuntu, we can change this by editing AndroidStudioPath/bin/studio.sh.
2. Also if you need reset android studio settings, Instead of reinstalling you can try this. Remove the .AndroidStudio3.3 folder in home location for ubuntu. In windows this will be the same but location will be  different which is C:\Users\.AndroidStudio3.3

Comment: I can't find way how to do it on Windows... Any idea?

Comment: Check in the path where andoid-studio.exe is present, there might be some files like settings.ini or config.ini or something similar. I have only used android studio in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, may be work for you,

Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions

Open it with notepad with administrative permission and change the following attributes:

-Xmx512m to -Xmx256m

-XX:MaxPermSize=250m to -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Or change:

-Xmx750m to -Xmx512m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m to -XX:MaxPermSize=250m

Comment: edited my question, take a look please. Added that you asked, but it does not helped

Comment: i think you should reinstalled JDK and reset path because if your JAVA command is working and JAVAC not, then problem defiantly in path set

Comment: Ok, and also, how you can explain that Android Studio 3.2 is working and Android Studio 3.3 not?

Comment: yeap... because of this I am confused

Comment: then you can verify jdk path from studio 3.2 and 3.3

Comment: It is exactly that @JibinNajeeb told... Take a look at his answer. And he suggest to change in in settings, but nobody know where is settings file located...

Answer (score 0):

simple android studio requires pointing to the jdk jre installed whereas you are pointing to the jre...look in your jdk folder and you will see the jre folder location you need to use in your java_home setting.

Answer (score 0):

windows: check your system environment variant, if has STUDIO_VMOPTIONS variant, delete it, just use defaut vmoptions